# roles toArray() issue on symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm following the symofny documentation to creating the login system but when I try to create a a form to create a new user I get this error, I've been looking for a solution for nothing seems to work.

`FatalErrorException: Error: Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object in var/www/Frigorifico/src/Frigorifico/FrigorificoBundle/Entity/Users.php line 90`

```
private $roles;

public function ___construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}

 public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should not use:

```
public function ___construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

but:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

see more at [official php documenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: Take attention on the underscores before construct. 3 vs 2

Comment: the issue is that I already have a __construct() function in the class and I can't assign both variables in the same __contruct()